# Can not find Symbol Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on v23

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am compile code with following build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

For accessing saving photo into SDCARD i have opened permission Dialog box for V23

like below screenshot

[image]

But I am getting following error that

**Can not find Symbol Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

I have put sdkVersion to 23 but why i am still getting this error

Comment: As of Android 23 EVERY thing has changed!!!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Finally I found that Menifest file is autogenerated by Android Studio

In AndroideMenifest i have written following code for ParsePushNotification

```
 <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

and below menifest file is generated

[image]

So when i have written code below it's works

**android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

instead of

**Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

Comment: Thanks!! This was driving me nuts!

Comment: Or you can just import android.Manifest.

Comment: Why is `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ` bothered by `C2D_MESSAGE` permission? I have same issue. In my case I need to use `C2D_MESSAGE` from Manifest, rather than android.Manifest...

Comment: Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE : not working means you are importing wrong one. I have imported java.util.jar, and getting this error

Answer (score 45):

Only write Android before manifest class. Change:

Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR

to:

android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR

Answer (score 10):

I think you can use Manifest class from android in android.Manifest.permission or android.Manifest.permission_group. For detail permission types you can read from this [Manifest.permission](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html), see this

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

Comment: Do, import android.Manifest . It will solve the issue. _Thanks

Answer (score 4):

the solution to this problem is simple..just add the word "android" before the word "manifest".

android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR

Answer (score 3):

Read [this article](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) please.

Since the permission system is redesigned there are some permissions that need access to be revoked and some others that do not. The specific permission that you request is in a group that is called `android.permission-group.STORAGE`. Check this out.

Try this out:

```
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                     REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions are here :

**1.** Add `import android.Manifest` to the imports section.
**2.** Add the `android` keyword before the permission name (e.g. **android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA**)

Answer (score 0):

Just Write android before Manifest.permission.WRITE
Example : android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?