# Error at Manifest.permission.CAMERA

Tags: java, android-studio

I am requesting permissions for camera in android studio, but it raising the error at Manifest.permission.CAMERA

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

[image]

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: cannot find symbol CAMERA

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34139211/6300600)

Answer (score 13):

Use `android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA` in place `Manifest.permission.CAMERA`

refer to: [Can not find Symbol Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on v23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472723/can-not-find-symbol-manifest-permission-write-external-storage-on-v23)

Comment: I think this is incorrect because: android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA ==Manifest.permission.CAMERA